# Blazor / Javascript Render Issue

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, openlayers, .net-6.0

I'm currently experiencing a strange issue involving blazor, javascript and the javascript library open layers. I have 2 components one called search criteria and another called search results. When the user clicks search, blazor loads the map results page and the javascript function to load the map gets called.

This works most of the time, but there's a intermittent issue when I load the map component the map is not being rendered. The console windows has a warning saying "**No map visible because the map container's width or height are 0**". Which doesnt make sense because the width and height are set in css so should never be 0. I'm assuming its a timing issue between blazor and javascript but I'm not sure.

Blazor Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/routes.css">
<PageTitle>Officer Locator</PageTitle>

@if (employeeCoordinates.Any())
{
    @foreach (var coordinate in employeeCoordinates)
    {
        <input type="hidden" class="employeeCoordinates" value="@coordinate.EmployeeId"     data-latitude="@coordinate.Latitude" data-longitude="@coordinate.Longitude" data-    displaytext="@coordinate.DisplayText" />
}
<br />
<div class="row col-lg-12 green-heading">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div>Current Time: @DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm")</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row col-lg-12">
    <div id="map" @ref="mapElement">        
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<p>Choose an item from the following list(s) in order to center the map on it.</p>
<div class="row col-lg-8">
    <label asp-for="centerOn" class="col-lg-5 col-form-label">Displayed Items</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <select class="form-select long-select" aria-label="centerOn" name="centerOn" id="centerOn">
            @foreach (var coordinate in employeeCoordinates)
            {
                <option data-latitude="@coordinate.Latitude" data-longitude="@coordinate.Longitude" value="@coordinate.EmployeeId">@coordinate.DisplayText</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="mapEndpoint" value="@mapEndpoint" data-endpoint="@mapEndpoint" />
}
else
{    
    <div class="alert alert-warning row col-lg-12" role="alert">
        No officers found for that search criteria
    </div>
}
<br />
<br />

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? olModule;
    private IJSObjectReference? routeMapModule;    
    private ElementReference mapElement;
    private List<OfficerCoordinatesDto> employeeCoordinates = new();
    private string mapEndpoint = string.Empty;

    [Parameter]
    public List<OfficerCoordinatesDto> SearchResults { get; set; } = new ();    
       

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {                
        mapEndpoint = _config["MapIntegration:MapEndpoint"];
        employeeCoordinates = SearchResults;
    }
    

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            olModule = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/ol.js");
            routeMapModule = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/employee-map.js");            
            await routeMapModule.InvokeVoidAsync("addEmployeeMap");
        }
    }       

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (olModule is not null)
        {
            await olModule.DisposeAsync();
        }
        if (routeMapModule is not null)
        {
            await routeMapModule.DisposeAsync();
        }        
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
export function addEmployeeMap() {
    const employeeLong = $('.employeeCoordinates').first().data('longitude')
    const employeeLat = $('.employeeCoordinates').first().data('latitude')
    const mapEndpoint = $('#mapEndpoint').data('endpoint');

    let featuresToAdd = [];
    const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ features: [] });


    $.each($(".employeeCoordinates"), function (i, obj) {
        const employeeId = obj.value;
        const long = obj.dataset.longitude;
        const lat = obj.dataset.latitude;
        const displayText = obj.dataset.displaytext;

        const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat])),
            name: employeeId
        });

        const iconStyle = new ol.style.Style(
            {
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    text: displayText,
                    font: 'bold 12px Arial',
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'blue', }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'white', width: 2, }),
                    textBaseline: 'hanging',
                    offsetY: 15
                })
            });

        const pointStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 9,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: 'green' }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: 'white', width: 2 })
            })
        });

        iconFeature.setStyle([pointStyle, iconStyle]);
        featuresToAdd.push(iconFeature);
    });


    vectorSource.addFeatures(featuresToAdd);

    const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });
    const mapImageLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: mapEndpoint
        })
    });


    const view = new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([employeeLong, employeeLat]),
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-8.77, 49.61, 1.95, 60.93], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        minZoom: 7,
        maxZoom: 16,
        zoom: 12
    });

    const map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [mapImageLayer, vectorLayer],        
        target: 'map',
        view: view
    });

    // Center on point when dropdown is changed
    const center = document.getElementById('centerOn');
    center.addEventListener(
        'change',
        function () {
            if ($('#centerOn :selected').text()) {
                let centerLong = $('#centerOn :selected').data('longitude');
                let centerLat = $('#centerOn :selected').data('latitude');

                let coordinate = ol.proj.fromLonLat([centerLong, centerLat]);

                view.setCenter(coordinate);
            };
        },
        false
    );
}
```

Comment: i had the same problem when i was rendering map in blazor using Leaflet, try to assign height and width in style of the div that contains map and see, most probably it will show up, after that you can use css to style it the way you want.

Comment: Also `<div id="mapElement"></div>` does not contain any content so how will it assign any height to it, its just an empty div, map gets rendered after js is called, this is what i understood.

Comment: you can also assign height to it in the same js where you are rending map using DOM. if its just a small div on a webpage, in my application whole page was suppose to be a map so i got away with predefined heigh and width.

Comment: @WajeehHasan Sorry I have a css file that applies the height and width style to the html element with the id mapElement. I just forgot to add here. I got this issue resolved though, I added the width and height styling to the js file and it worked. No idea why must have been a timing issue between the rendering /applying css for the blazor page and the running of the js